# SQL - how to SELECT multiple tables and JOIN multiple rows from the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

How to SELECT multiple tables and JOIN multiple rows from the same column?

It does not return `painting.id_group`, `painting.id_type` and `painting.id_location`.
I'm sure this SQL snippet has wrong syntax.

```
SELECT painting.id, painting.order, painting_en.url, id_portfolio.en
FROM painting
LEFT JOIN painting_en
USING ( id ) 
LEFT JOIN id_portfolio ON id_portfolio.id = painting.id_group
AND id_portfolio.id = painting.id_type
AND id_portfolio.id = painting.id_location
WHERE painting_en.url='2011-name3'
LIMIT 1
```

**Update:**
It shows `Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)`.
After removing

```
AND id_portfolio.id = painting.id_type
AND id_portfolio.id = painting.id_location
```

it returns:

```
id        | order | url        |en
----------+-------+------------+-----
09518709  | 4     | 2011-name3 | NULL
```

but I need to return:

```
id        | order | url        | group   | type          | location
----------+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------
09518709  | 4     | 2011-name3 | realism | oil on canvas | US
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return them? Does the grid returned only have 1 column?

Comment: I updated my question with SQL result and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to same table multiple times you just need to give different aliases

```
SELECT painting.id, 
       painting.order, 
       painting_en.url, 
       `group`.en AS `group`, 
       TYPE.en AS type, 
       location.en AS location
FROM   painting 
       LEFT JOIN painting_en 
       USING (id) 
       LEFT JOIN id_portfolio `group` 
         ON `group`.id = painting.id_group 
       LEFT JOIN id_portfolio TYPE 
         ON TYPE.id = painting.id_type 
       LEFT JOIN id_portfolio location 
         ON location.id = painting.id_location 
WHERE  painting_en.url = '2011-name3' 
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: MySQL returns error *#1054 - Unknown column 'id_portfolio.en' in 'field list'* for `SELECT painting.id, painting.order, painting_en.url, id_portfolio.en AS  'group' , id_portfolio.en AS  'type' , id_portfolio.en AS location
FROM painting
LEFT JOIN painting_en
USING ( id ) 
LEFT JOIN id_portfolio 'group' ON id_portfolio.id = painting.id_group
LEFT JOIN id_portfolio 'type' ON id_portfolio.id = painting.id_type
LEFT JOIN id_portfolio location ON id_portfolio.id = painting.id_location
WHERE painting_en.url =  '2011-name3'
LIMIT 1`

Comment: That's because you need to use the table alias in the SELECT clause not the actual table name

Comment: Your SQL must be working fine. MySQL returned me before *#1054 - Unknown column 'id_portfolio.en' in 'field list'* because of some missed column in db. It's now fixed. Also for better performance - do not use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` if there are not such a need.