# SQL: How to return two more row data from table `property`?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - how to SELECT multiple tables and JOIN multiple rows from the same column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087444/sql-how-to-select-multiple-tables-and-join-multiple-rows-from-the-same-column)

I have three **MySQL** tables - `language`, `category` and `property`

```
/*
table `language`
`WHERE language.url='link'`*/
id   | url
-----+-----
111  | link

/*
table `category`
`SELECT category.id, category.order`*/
id   | order  | group | type | location
-----+--------+-------+------+---------
111  | 3      | a42   | a81  | a63

/*
table `property`
`LEFT JOIN properties ON properties.id = category.group`*/
id  | status
----+-------
a42 | public
a81 | update
a63 | states
```

and SQL

```
SELECT category.id, category.order, language.url, property.status AS `group`
FROM category
LEFT JOIN language
USING ( id )
LEFT JOIN property ON property.id = category.group
WHERE language.url='link'
LIMIT 1
```

that returns

```
id  | order | url   | group
----+-------+-------+-------
111 | 3     | link  | public
```

**SQL: How to return two more row data from table `property` so that result would be:**

```
id  | order | url   | group  | type   | location
----+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------
111 | 3     | link  | public | update | states
```

Comment: You should really edit your existing question rather than asking another, or alternatively delete one.

Comment: I preffer to close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087444/sql-how-to-select-multiple-tables-and-join-multiple-rows-from-the-same-column

Comment: That's fine, but you may not get the votes you need. A moderator can do it if you flag the question and in the text box explain that you opened two questions and want to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need 2 more `LEFT JOIN`s

```
SELECT category.id, category.order, language.url
   , g.status AS `group`, t.status AS `type`, l.status AS `location`
FROM category
LEFT JOIN language
USING ( id )
LEFT JOIN property AS g ON category.group = g.id
LEFT JOIN property AS t ON category.type = t.id 
LEFT JOIN property AS l ON category.location = l.id 
WHERE language.url='link'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin returns error *#1054 - Unknown column 'g.status' in 'field list'*

Comment: you received that error when running the entire query in my answer?  Are you able to add an alias of `g` to your current `LEFT JOIN property` and change your select to `g.status` instead of `property.status`?

Comment: I tried your advice on MySQL 5.5.16, and it still returns the same error *ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'g.status' in 'field list'*

Comment: Thanks! It actually works, my mysql db missed some column before. For better performance - do not use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` if there are not such a need.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  I used `LEFT JOIN`s because they were in your original post, and I was not sure if there would always be a value for each status for each category.  I agree with you on `INNER JOIN`s though, where appropriate.